# How to distribute data within an ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I want to create an app which uses a SQLITE 3 (Core Data) database. One table of this database has 100.000 datasets. How can I distribute this database content within my app. The first run of the app should load this initial data into the table. How can I do this? Can I export and import the whole database, or can I extract a csv file? How works the import of the csv file? What is the best practice? Thanks Jens

Comment: You dont have to distribute the database contents, you can have a single DB. Coredata is pretty optimized in itself, as such it provides various tools to load and deal with large set of data (in general), You can make use of `NSFetchResultsController` to query and populate your table, FetchResultsControllers works on the principle of `page fault` what it means is if you specify the fetch batch size as 10, even if your query results in finding 1000 rows it will load only 10 actual objects into memory and will hold remaining as page fault entry, when you scroll the tableView and try to actually

Comment: access the object which is not yet loaded, it will result in page fault and core data will actually load that object to memory, Kind of lazy loading core data objects to memory as and when needed. So even if you are dealing with considerably huge amount of data, you might not load all of them at once and hence your app performance will not be hampered. That being said, 100000 data sets? seems like this is use case for server, do you really need to hold that number of data sets? Cant you load them from server and load them as n when needed? Even though coredata optimizes the object loading into

Comment: memory, I guess if user ends up scrolling and eventually load all objects, memory foot print of the app will be too huge and will result in iOS terminating your app by throwing out of memory error :|

Comment: If I understand it right. When I insert data into my core data sqlit 3 db and after that I distribute the app to the app store. Does the data still exists in the app so that everybody who downloads the app can use this data? I think not. So how can I bring the data and the app into the app store?

Comment: You can save your initial data into a CSV file and make it part of the app bundle, in application did finish launch, you can read the data from CSV file and add the data to Coredata and finally to SQLite file by calling `save` on managed object context of CoreData, I would create a child managedObject context associated with background queue to offload the data parsing task from main queue and to keep main thread unblocked. Also because application did finish launch gets called multiple times and you wouldnt wanna save these data to sqlite again n again, I would keep some kind of checks before

Comment: blindly calling data parsing and updating coredata, You can find lots of tutorials one such I can find is https://www.raywenderlich.com/7586-multiple-managed-object-contexts-with-core-data-tutorial

Comment: IMO less you store on device, the better. Also if you have a lot of data, using CoreData, or local storage is a terrible idea. E.g. if each of 100000 datasets is just 1KB, that's almost 100 MB of data - is it necessary? You also will be responsible for managing/cleaning that data on user device. Not to mention that any change in schema between versions with CoreData is a nightmare. Instead, use some server-side storage - Firebase for example, or AWS.

Comment: Have you thought about on demand resources? They're hosted by Apple and you can purge them later https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Tagging.html

Comment: Yes I see the problem of loading big data in the device, but I only have 5.000 datasets with a litte text and 4 floats. I think this is ok.